# How to create an alert with HTML instead of js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to create an HTML element that is like the [JavaScript confirm();](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm) element. I would be fine with just using the JS element, but I am not able to edit the style. Am I able to do this?
Thank You!

Comment: Popular frameworks with modals: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), [Polymer](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Bootstrap alerts for example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

There is also http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Craig's answer, try out the following code to use the Bootstrap framework for an alert that is indeed editable.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xqhtt1oa/)